# how to minimize the map in the google maps activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

how can i change the size and position of the map in android studio (i used google maps activity) so that i can place a navigation drawer inside the layout.
This is my code in the map layout

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="gomugomu.e_radauti_gomugomu.Map"
tools:layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_draw" />
```

Comment: You will just need to put the Fragment inside an enclosing Layout, and use a Toolbar if you want to use a NavigationDrawer.

Comment: my map is not a fragment :( and for the nav i have the layout already done i just need to include it but when i include it and run the map hide the nav

Comment: You should actually just use a Fragment that extends SupportMapFragment for using in a NavigationDrawer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687517/how-to-use-a-google-map-in-a-navigationdrawer